# How to find what my custom command line command refers to

Tags: command-line

Some long time ago I've created a script which I've added to my Ubuntu system and I'm able to call it simply with call to command `rec`

```
MeUser@MyMachine:~$ rec
```

The problem is that now I'd like to extend the command but I can't figure out where the script can be found and what the `rec` command refers to.

I assume I can do it (it's Ubuntu after all) but it's not so simple - I've already looked into `~/.bashrc` but I did not find anything which refers to `rec`. Where else can I search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You installed it somewhere in your `$PATH` when you can call it just like that in the command line. Use `type` to find out where:

```
type rec
rec is /usr/local/bin/rec
```

Or maybe it's an alias, then it whould look like:

```
rec is aliased to `myscript --with --some --parameters blah'
```

You can then use `type` on `myscript` to find out where it lays.

Comment: Thanks it helped when I did `type rec` I got `rec is hashed (/usr/bin/rec)`

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` you can locate files on your `$PATH` with the `which` command. eg:

```
which rec
```

And you can list aliases with the `alias` command. Simply type `alias`.

You will find your script with one these.